# Android app doesn't show the "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" notice

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

> Take a look at the following screenshots:

**Desktop version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913943/infinite-scroll-repeate-same-id-again-from-database/36914466#36914466):**
[image]

**And the mobile version:**
[image]

**The notice doesn't appear in the app. Is it a bug?**

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device: LG G3

Comment: While it may be a bug, SE app doesn't support chat, so moving it to chat will make it more complicated.